# Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've got no clues on how it worked but just did

Answer (score 2):

I added `@ResponseBody` annotation on the related controller and the problem has solved.

*Note: I work on adding an entity by another rest service.*

Before:

```
@PostMapping("/bayiKaydet")
    public Bayi bayiKaydet(@RequestBody Bayi bayi) {
        serverUrl += "bayiKaydet";
        
        restTemplate.postForEntity(serverUrl, bayi, Bayi.class);
        serverUrl = "http://localhost:8090/";
        return bayi;
    }
```

After:

```
@PostMapping("/bayiKaydet")
    @ResponseBody
    public Bayi bayiKaydet(@RequestBody Bayi bayi) {
        serverUrl += "bayiKaydet";
        
        restTemplate.postForEntity(serverUrl, bayi, Bayi.class);
        serverUrl = "http://localhost:8090/";
        return bayi;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my project, it was just solved by making my Controller class  as @RestController

ex...

@RestController