# Error resolving template [], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Below is my controller. As you see I want to return `html` type

```
@Controller
public class HtmlController {

  @GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
  public Employee html() {
    return Employee.builder()
      .name("test")
      .build();
  }
}
```

I initial got following error:

```
Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again
```

I fixed it up by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801941/circular-view-path-login-would-dispatch-back-to-the-current-handler-url-log) post.

Now I am getting another error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Can someone help me with **why I have to rely on thymleaf for serving a html content** and why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why I have to rely on Thymeleaf for serving HTML content

You don't. You can do it in other ways, you just have to tell Spring that that's what you're doing, i.e. by telling it that the return value is the response itself, not the name of the view using to generate the response.

As the [**Spring documentation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types) says:

> The next table describes the supported controller method return values.
>
> - **`String`**: A view name to be resolved with `ViewResolver` implementations and used together with the implicit model — determined through command objects and `@ModelAttribute` methods. The handler method can also programmatically enrich the model by declaring a `Model` argument.
> - **`@ResponseBody`**: The return value is converted through `HttpMessageConverter` implementations and written to the response. See [`@ResponseBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-responsebody).
> - ...
> - **Any other return value**: Any return value that does not match any of the earlier values in this table [...] is treated as a view name (default view name selection through `RequestToViewNameTranslator` applies).

In your code, how does an `Employee` object get turned into `text/html`? Right now, the code falls into the "Any other return value" category, and that fails.

You could, e.g.

- Use a Thymeleaf template *(this is the recommended way)*:

  ```
  @GetMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
  public String html(Model model) { // <== changed return type, added parameter
      Employee employee = Employee.builder()
          .name("test")
          .build();
      model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
      return "employeedetail"; // view name, aka template base name
  }
  ```
- Add a `String toHtml()` method to `Employee` and then do:

  ```
  @GetMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody // <== added annotation
  public String html() { // <== changed return type (HTML is text, i.e. a String)
      return Employee.builder()
          .name("test")
          .build()
          .toHtml(); // <== added call to build HTML content
  }
  ```

  This actually uses a built-in [`StringHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html).
- Use a registered [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) *(not recommended)*:

  ```
  @GetMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody // <== added annotation
  public Employee html() {
      return Employee.builder()
          .name("test")
          .build();
  }
  ```

  This of course requires that you write a `HttpMessageConverter<Employee>` implementation that supports `text/html`, and [register it](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest#config) with the Spring Framework.